# pass a variable length array of styles to a macro

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to write a macro to use with tikz. The idea is, that I have a rectangle which is shaded differently in different areas.

This is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\projectionLayer}{mmm}{
    % #1 lower left corner
    % #2 number of concatenated projections
    % #3 size of projections

    \FPeval{\size}{(#2)*(#3)}
    \begin{scope}[shift={#1}]
        \draw [line width=1.2pt, fill=yellow] (0,0) rectangle (\size,1);
        \foreach \s in {1,...,#2}{
            \FPeval{\pos}{\s*(#3)}
            \draw[very thick] (\pos, 0) -- (\pos,1);
        }
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \projectionLayer{(0, 0)}{11}{2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know that there is `<{\SplitList{,}}o` or similar but I didn't found out how to access it by index (ie in the `\foreach` loop with `\s`
Maybe I misunderstood the concept of LaTeX here and there is a much more elegant way to do this.

The desired output would be, that for example the first two lines are dashed, the second 3 lines are dotted and so on...

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please make this into a full minimal example that others can copy and use as is. That makes it a **lot** easier for others to help

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you add some scheme (even handmade) which shows something similar to desired final result? Your code draws a yellow long rectangle which is later on covered by empty little rectangles. Where is shading?